# Magento2 Add custom form in order view but url don't correct

Tags: magento2, javascript, sales-order, url, tabs

I have a problem when add a custom tabs in order view.
In new tabs, I have html form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('giftvoucheradmin/giftvoucher/addcodetoorder') ?>" method="POST">               
            // something in here
</form>
```

However, when I click button it alway redirect to admin dashboard. I have try view console and coppy this url and open another window then action work well
May I help you? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is Helpful for you,

Update your template with formkey:

```
<form action="<?php echo $block->getUrl('giftvoucheradmin/giftvoucher/addcodetoorder') ?>" method="POST">               
            // something in here

  <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $block->getFormKey() ?>" />
</form>
```

Add getFormKey() into you block

```
public function getFormKey(){

    return $this->formKey->getFormKey();
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/6ea7d2d85cded3fa0fbcf4e7aa0dcd4edbf568a6/app/code/Magento/Backend/view/adminhtml/templates/admin/formkey.phtml